# How to put a link on <div> tag in IOS

Tags: ios, html

I noticed that this :

```
<a href = "somelink">
   <div class = "samplecalssname">

   </div>
</a>
```

is not working on IOS devices, there should be a link on the div isnt it?

Comment: Does it have content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it, i just need to define the height and width of the div tag since it doesn't have any content is seems invisible on the screen.. on the css file i just added :

```
.samplecalssname{
   height : 100px;
   width : 100px;
}
```

and this worked fine.